# PHP MySQL Random

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-update

If I have 2 MySQL database with the following fields...

```
RequestDB:
 - Username 
 - Category

DisplayDB:
 - Username 
 - Category
 - Balance
 - URL
```

...is it possible to generate a random URL entry if other criteria is met?  Also can values from one database be compared to another?  And finally, once the random field is generated, can other values from that same entry be edited.  For example:

```
IF Display.Category = Request.Category 
  AND Display.Balance > 0 
THEN Print Random URL 
  AND Display.Balance = Display.Balance - 0.10
```

I know the above is not PHP.  I'm much more use to VB.net but I'm sure the above can be "translated" in to PHP.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could make use of MySQL's [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function

Comment: Do you want the random URL to be a random url in any random database row? If so, simply query the rows in the display. Since the DisplayDB doesn't have an ID to associate as a primary key I am imagining that you're going to have to get all the URL's in an array and then count how many rows they are an then to get which one you want to use from the array you'll need to use rand(0, $count) as the function to create that random selection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT requestdb.*, display.* FROM requestdb INNER JOIN display ON requestdb.category=display.category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
$display_url = $row['url'];
}
echo $display_url;
```